# What to add in CarouselView Custom Renderer to get rid of keyboard issue in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have an app in Xamarin Forms, and the android app has a bug where I click on the NumericEntry to enter some values, which brings the keyboard up, but then when I close the keyboad, it just leaves this gray rectangle where it used to be, pushing my whole carousel view up.

[image]

I can swipe up and down on the top half of it fine, and when I swipe to the side to go the the next page, the rectangle disappears, "resetting" the carousel view's layout.

I've done everything I can like altering the WindowSoftInputMode, tried to do make some changes in XAML, but I think a custom renderer is inevitable. I'm not sure what I element I can alter or what I can do in it to make this problem go away though.

Here's the page.XAML

```
<CarouselView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingList}" 
                   Position="{Binding Position}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollView>
          <StackLayout> ....... All MY CODE ..... </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  </CarouselView>
```

Thanks!

edit: Gif of the problem

[image]

Comment: is this a known bug?  Have you filed a bug report with Xamarin?

Comment: Post your viewmodel as well

Comment: I'd also reconsider using a ScrollView inside the template - nested scrollable containers usually cause problems

Comment: I tried removing the scroll view but.. obviously my page couldn't scroll down anymore, what would you recommend instead? And I've seen a lot of posts online about it but it doesn't seem to have been fixed, just a lot of suggestions to change the AndroidManifest.xml's WindowSoftInputMode but it doesn't seem to be helping @Jason

Comment: I already suggested filing a bug with Xamarin

Comment: Yes, but is there nothing I can do other than waiting for Xamarin? @Jason

Comment: other people than Xamarin monitor the github and may be able to offer suggestions on workarounds, etc

Comment: @Jason Actually I just tried moving the ScrollView outside all of that an it worked

Comment: @Jason Well the keyboard issue is gone but I can only scroll a little bit..

Comment: What is your nuget package‘s version, my xamarin forms version is `4.3.0.908675` Here is my running GIF, it worked as normal.You can see this thread:https://imgur.com/a/Ubfrpk0

Comment: If you want to use ScrollView you should be using a Non-Scrollable carousel container!

Comment: What's a non-scrollable carousel? Do you mean verticall or horizontally? @FreakyAli

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I'm running 4.4.0.991477

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I made an edit with a gif of what is happening in mine

Comment: I change my layout and update nugetpackages to  4.4.0.991477 like yours, here is running gif https://imgur.com/a/GEKsqWU, can you upload a demo to github and share a link.